What is the best way to use concatenated values in an XLOOKUP formula with a large result range?
I have a sheet that looks similar to this:

I'd like to write a formula that uses cells B1 and C1 as criteria and returns the value in column A in the table shown. I have the following formula written:
=XLOOKUP($B$1,$E$2:$E$37,XLOOKUP($A$5,$G$1:$L$1,$G$2:$L$37)

This works fine if there is only one cell (B1) being searched, however when I try it with B1&C1 to match columns E and F it gives me an error: "Array arguments to XLOOKUP are of different size"
There are a couple of caveats to this:

C1 may be blank
The order in which the values on B1 and C1 are displayed may not necessarily be the same order in columns E and F so the formula would need to adjust for this (for example if B1 is "Water" and C1 is "Rock", this should produce the same result if C1 is "Rock" and B1 is "Water")

Ideally, I'd like to do this without an IFERROR or ISNA formula. Does this require an ARRAYFORMULA to work?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AieSI6BM473HwKlH7sUWtHvdjlwtSSk4xNo0SLdYEgk


Here's one approach: xmatch is used to look for either or match of WaterRock and RockWater for every row here
=tocol(xlookup(1,map(E:E,F:F,lambda(e,f,xmatch(B1&C1,{e&f,f&e})^0)),G:L))


Alternative:
=tocol(xlookup(true,map(E:E,F:F,lambda(e,f,or(B1&C1=e&f,B1&C1=f&e))),G:L))


try:
=INDEX(TOCOL(VLOOKUP(B1&C1, {E2:E&F2:F, G2:L; F2:F&E2:E, G2:L}, {2,3,4,5,6,7}, 0)))


